# cakephp upload function - move_uploaded_file issue

Tags: php, cakephp, upload

I'm making an upload function in cakephp, what its suppose to do is upload an image 
and move it to the app/webroot/media directory then save the image name to the database so that 
it can be called using a function.

Currently, it can upload an image and save the image name in the database, but it doesnt move the file to the 
app/webroot/media directory.I tried to break the code part by part and double checked the functions that i used, but I can't seem to find the problem. I was hoping a diffrent pair of eyes could enlighten me. Any help/suggestions is very much appreciated tnx.

```
public function upload() {
if (!empty($this->request->data['ModelName']['name'])) {
$file = $this->request->data['ModelName']['name']; 

$path = $file['name'];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$path2 = $file['tmp_name'];
$ext2 = pathinfo($path2, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

$arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','png'); 

if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) {
move_uploaded_file($ext2, APP_DIR . '/webroot/media/' . $file['name']);
$this->request->data['ModelName']['name'] = $file['name'];
}
}

if($this->ModelName->save($this->request->data)) {
echo 'saved';
} else {
echo 'not saved';
}
$this->autoRender = FALSE;
$this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading image with move_uploaded_file() ,In first parameter you just take whole tmp file (ie, $path2 ). In 2nd parameter you can directly use fullpath of the webroot by "WWW_ROOT/media"

Answer (score 0):

code from my controller.Hope this will help you.

```
if(!empty($this->data['Post']['filename']['name']))
            {
                $file=$this->data['Post']['filename'];
                $ary_ext=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); //array of allowed extensions
                $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                if(in_array($ext, $ary_ext))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'media/' . time().$file['name']);
                    $this->request->data['Post']['filename'] = time().$file['name'];
                }
            }
```